# How to avoid selecting too many data

Tags: apache-spark

What we are doing is pretty much like

1. putting time series data into cassandra
2. running an spark aggregation job every hour and put aggregated data back to cassandra

One of the problems we found is, if the hourly job does not succeed, for example, continuously, 1 AM ~ 2 AM, 2 AM ~ 3 AM, 3 AM ~ 4 AM (or more), then next time, it'll aggregate the data from 1 AM to 5 AM (last success time is recorded in cassandra).  The issue comes at this hour, because it's now 4 (or more) hours data, and it's way larger than one hour data which then results in an `OutofMemory` exception by selecting too many data from cassandra into dataframe.

Well, adding memory to spark executor is a way fixing this.  However, considering it's an edge issue, I'm wondering if there's any mature pattern or architecture to deal with this issue.

Comment: Maybe your query (processing pipeline) is not scalable. Can you share your code?

Comment: it's not easy to share the code, but the logic is simple.  The hourly aggregation job starts at the 20th minute of an hour.  what it does is

1. Query a table to get the last success time, for example it's 1:23 AM which means the last success job was done at 1:23 AM.
2. Check current time, if it's 2:20 AM, use `from` = 1:00 AM, and `to` = 2:00 AM.  So, if it's 6:20 AM, `to` = 6 AM
3. Build the cql by `from` and `to`, for example, `select * from table_name where time_col < to and time_col > from`

Don't query understand `query (processing pipeline) is not scalable`.  Would you elaborate?